# PHP - Count items in object

Tags: php

I'm using [Kirby CMS](http://getkirby.com) and I need to find out how many posts I have.

My posts are gotten with

```
$posts = $pages->find('posts')->children();
```

which echos an `object` with 10 items (links to the posts).

It is not an array so using `count()` returns 1.

How can I count the items in this object like I would with an array?

Comment: what does var_dump( $posts );  show?

Comment: maybe you can conver it to an array

Comment: is it like a string? is there a delimiter between each posts?

Comment: @marabutt var_dump shows a whole massive bunch of stuff, which I guess is all the data about all the posts.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer can you add it to your post?

Comment: @artsylar echo results in the links to the posts being seperated by <br /> tags if that's what you mean.

Comment: @marabutt No, it's hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: @marabutt What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with this library. But try this, it *might* work:

```
$count = $pages->find('posts')->children()->count();
```